# How should I delete a container to allow its disk space to be claimed by another container?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, big-sur, filesystem, monterey

On my 2017 Macbook Air, running Big Sur, I created a new "container" to install Monterey to test it.   So I have a dual-boot system with Big Sur and Monterey living on two separate containers (along with separate copies of all my user and other files).  Here is the `diskutil list` ...

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         119.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         119.9 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +119.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨for_monterey - Data⁩     60.7 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨for_monterey⁩            15.7 GB    disk1s3
   3:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.7 GB    disk1s3s1
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 274.5 MB   disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      3.2 GB     disk1s6

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +119.9 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨BigSurHD - Data⁩         64.8 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 317.5 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                626.3 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨BigSurHD⁩                15.3 GB    disk2s5
```

I'm happy with Monterey, so I want to delete Big Sur and make my entire disk available to Monterey.

Can I simply go to DiskUtility and delete the Big Sur container, thereby ending up with a single container filling my entire disk ?  It appears not; if I click on "Partition" in the DiskUtility, while booted into Monterey, the '-' button is greyed out for BigSur.

So must I clone my Monterey container onto an external disk, wipe the internal disk, and restore the Monterey container back? I believe I can do this with the Disk Utility too, using disk images; but I'm unclear on the exact steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure suppress Big Sur and replace it by Monterey, you can do that (I suppose you have a save TM or CCC of you Big Sur install) :

From Monterey you clone the Monterey install on the Big Sur Container :

```
sudo asr --source /dev/disk1s3s1 --target /dev/disk2 --erase
```

You will be asked to enter your password which is not displayed when you type it and then you will have to validate the deletion of the ex-Big Sur Container.

Then the copy will take about 5 or 10 minutes.

Then you boot on the new Monterey, with the Alt key and you choice the thirst "⁨for_monterey" item.

Your two install will have the same name and you verify that you are on the good Container (the first).
The command :

```
diskutil list
```

Give you this information.

The active container have a “APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-..” volume.

If ok you suppress  the second (original) Monterey Container :

```
diskutil ap deletecontainer diskx tokill
```

then

```
diskutil erasevolume free space disk0s3
```

And you add the free space to your new Monterey install

```
diskutil ap resizecontainer disky 0b
```

**Of course diskx and disky must be replaced by the real values given by the command** :

```
diskutil list
```

If you have a doubt after the reboot on the new Monterey Volume, you give the results of the command :

```
diskutil list
```

And I will give you the appropriate commands.

Comment: Thanks.  I got impatiet last night though, and wiped the disk and did a clean install of Monterey, restoring my stuff from a TM backup.  It was kinda painful though.

Comment: No worries, there are always several ways to do it and the main thing is that everything works. Thanks for the feedback.